# Jean-air Cooktop Element always on high

Tags: switch

Model S 125.  I order a new infinity switch from Jean Air but the new part also maintains the element on high.  Can the new switch be defective also?  Is there a way to test the switch?

Comment: Perhaps neither switch is defective and you need to check other things.

Comment: There is not a lot to a restive element to go wrong. Your switch has to be some type of solid state switch , if it is wired properly the switch is about all that can go wrong. I see possibly 4 connections

Comment: Jenn Air is sending me a new switch.  From what I have read, there is nothing else that controls the heating element.  I have triple checked the wiring and it is all correct.  Testing the switch with a meter is the only way to determine if the switch is bad.